# how to remove double quotes from an Array

Tags: arrays, hive, hiveql

I had created a table in hive with ORC format and loaded data into the table. I have use collect_set to eliminate the duplicates as follows to insert the data. However, i see double quotes in the array. Is there anyway to remove those double quotes?

This is an sample data iim getting from table a and inserting into the table b using:

```
insert into table b 
select a.name as name, collect_set(b.sub) as subjects from a group by a.name;
```

my table be would be like this:

```
name   |     subjects
john   |   ["Eng", "Math", "Phy"]
Sarah  |   ["Math", "Chem"]
```

I want to get ride of the double quote in the array to look like this:

```
name   |     subjects
john   |   [Eng, Math, Phy]
Sarah  |   [Math, Chem]
```

Is there anyway to do this using hql?

Answer (score 0):

Array is an object and to be displayed it needs to be transformed to string.

When you select array, it is being transformed(serialized) to string. Hive displays array as comma separated values, double quoted, in square brackets.

Consider this example:

```
select array('Eng', 'Math', 'Phy');
```

Returns:

```
["Eng","Math","Phy"]
```

What I'm trying to say is that there is no double-quotes `"` in the initial data most probably, it is being serialized to String with double-quotes when you select it directly without explicit conversion to string.

If this is the real reason of double quotes in the select result, then the solution is to transform array to string explicitly:

```
select concat('[',concat_ws(',',array('Eng', 'Math', 'Phy')),']');
```

Returns:

```
[Eng,Math,Phy]
```

Is it what you expected?

If not and you really need to remove double-quotes from column value, then `regexp_replace` will do.

Example of array containing double quotes in the values:

```
select concat('[',concat_ws(',',array('"Eng"', '"Math"', '"Phy"')),']');
```

Returns:

```
["Eng","Math","Phy"]
```

In such case you can apply `regexp_replace` when loading your table

`regexp_replace(string, '["]', '')` --this will remove double-qutes

Your insert statement will look like this:

```
insert into table b select a.name as name, collect_set(regexp_replace(sub, '["]', '')) as subjects from a group by a.name;
```